# Difference between 'Save All' in IntelliJ and 'git commit'

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Git with IntelliJ for the first time and I am not sure what is the difference between using the 'Save All' option of IntelliJ and 'git commit' since both the options would allow me to locally save the changes I have made in the code.

Any sort of help on this topic would be great.

Comment: You should probably read some git manuals. Saving your changes in intellij has no relation to what happens in git. When you commit changes you create a commit which can then be later pushed etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IDEA's "Save All" option just saves all your file changes to your
  local disk. It does not perform any git (or other VCS) actions.
- `git commit` action performs a git operation: creates a git commit with all the files  you added (`git add`) to be committed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Helped me a lot and I am also starting to read some more about git flow.

Comment: You're welcome.

Just a small note that may be helpful:

https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ -- gitflow is one of commonly-used branching models.

Before learning branching models, I guess it can be useful for you to read about basics of working with git. See it for example here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.